# Victim of Community (Machine) Moderator?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits

Are my suggested edits wrong?

Here are the links of my suggested edits.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/590968
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/577808
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/561934
4. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/593752

These are the list of edits that I have suggested and got the rejection from no **human being** but a **community (machine) moderator**.

Please suggest me some way so that my edits are not rejected again.

I would always love to suggest some edits, so there is no reason for me to stop suggesting some correct edits, isn't it?

Comment: For the 4th entry. Why did you change wrong to wrond?

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe : Sir, I am surprised.I have just tried making the content body to be highlighted as a Code.I accept that it should not have been changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When an edit is rejected by the Community, it was automatically rejected because it conflicted with another edit.

For example, the original poster could have been editing the post at the same time, and that edit wins when a suggested edit conflicts with it. In this case, there was [another suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/577821) that won; that one was submitted later by someone that must have opened the editor before your suggestion was submitted. Because the other edit was approved before yours, yours lost.

Suggested edits normally need two approve or reject votes before its fate has been decided; your suggestion already had one approval vote before it was automatically rejected. You cannot do much about such rejections, it's just bad luck if it happens to you, it has nothing to do with the quality of your edit.

How to avoid these kinds of conflicts? The only way to avoid them is to not make edit suggestions at all; there always is a chance someone else submits an edit around the same time. That chance diminishes as the post in question ages, of course. Once you reach [2k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) you can edit posts directly and you'll be notified during editing if someone else submitted an edit at the same time.

Note that the Community Moderator also rejects an edit when a reviewer has decided to improve on your suggestion but mark the suggestion as not helpful. In that case, the edit history will show another edit that coincides with the rejection of the suggested edit. This was not the case with the specific suggestions you posted in your question though.

Comment: This is the 3-4th time I am getting rejected in the similar fashion  Sir.Is their any way that avoids rejection ?

Comment: The suggested edit that won was more recent, actually. I don't understand what happened here.

Comment: Gilles : I have suggested some 10 minutes before than that got Accepted.

Comment: @Gilles: Indeed, the relative time display threw me off, corrected.

Comment: I think these edits are rejected when someone "improves" your edit suggestion but marks it as unhelpful (read: you should have changed more/didn't change what you should have)

Comment: @BenBrocka: An improved edit shows up in the editing history, and can only be done by someone that has enough rep to do so. The next edit in the revision history of that post is from another suggested edit, made 3 minutes after the suggestion by the OP here. Clearly that suggestion wasn't an improvement on the OPs suggestion.

Comment: @Haresh Some of your edits are bad and *should* be rejected. Please stop abusing `\`backticks\``. They're for inline code *only*, they're not for adding emphasis to random words.

Comment: @Canada Ok..I will take care that.

Comment: @Haresh: Something wrong? Did you discover more information about why your *specific* edits were rejected?

Comment: @Haresh: In other words: Did you mean to un-accept my answer for a specific reason, and can I help remedy that?

Comment: Yes Sir...please see this Edit http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/590968..this edit was rejected today even if there was no reason for Conflict.i have accepted it as Correct but today your Answer was proved wrong by the Machine Moderator

Comment: @Haresh: That answer is an improved edit, where your edit was not marked as helpful. That's a *different* case from your previous edits, and my answer addressed those edits.

Comment: @Haresh: It's a little unfair to unaccept an answer to a specific question because a future event is slightly different. We *did* address the possibility of a rejection through an edit improvement, btw, see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145408/victim-of-community-machine-moderator/145409#comment415427_145409) *but that didn't apply to the edits in your original question*. I'll edit the possibility in, but I'd appreciate a heads-up next time.

Comment: Sir,I have Unaccepted your Answer not because I am not satisfied with your Answer, but to not Ask the Same Question twice.I feel sorry for that but it was intended in that way.

Comment: Sir,I felt that it was of no Use to ask the same thing again and  again in different Threads.

Comment: @Haresh: Your other option was to ask for clarification in a comment here; but the comments on this specific answer already addressed that possibility. I've added a paragraph discussing the other reason why there might be a Community Moderator rejection.

Comment: @Haresh: It's okay, but imagine hitting someone with a huge 7.5 * downvote, because there is an edge case you didn't quite yet understand.. :-)

Answer (score 4):

A suggested edit is also rejected by community if a reviewer used Improve and flagged the suggested edit as not helpfull.

Best ways to avoid rejections:

- only make substantial edits (not a single tag or a single spell error.
- fix anything you can think of.
- do not change the original meaning of the post
- do not change code
- don't introduce new mistakes
- don't introduce lots of bold/italic or backticks.
- don't introduce spam

Comment: Also, the other edit that was made to the post was from a low-rep user, it certainly wasn't the case here.

Comment: Gamecat is Toon Krijthe : Ok,then shouldn't I get Reject vote instead of Approve so that it doesn't require for any flagging Sir ?

Comment: Your suggestions only help to increase the chance the edit will be approved. They will not prevent automatic rejections due to a conflicting edit.

Comment: This is how it works, if a reviewer improves the post, it is either accepted or jejected by community (depends on the checkbox if the suggestion was useful).

Comment: You are right, but I still see this a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Someone else made essentially the same edit, I was one of the approvers the one that survived.

If you make an easy formatting-related edit it's likely that someone else is also gunning for the same easy edit, leading to a conflict and possible rejection. If it's an edit that needed additional work, someone may fix the *rest* of the post and uncheck "helpful" since you could have done more originally.

It's not necessarily you specifically.